# Does $ 18x + 7y ≡ 0 \pmod {m^2} \implies \max\{x,y\}>\frac{m^2}{25}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let, $M=\max\{x,y\}$. I found following -

> we have - $ 18x + 7y ≡ 0 \pmod {m^2}.$ Then $  M ≥ m^2/25 $.

The only possible way seems to be is that $ 18x + 7y ≡ 0 \pmod {m^2} \implies $ either $x$ or $y$ is divided by $m^2 \implies M=m^2k \implies M>\frac{m^2}{25}$.

But I can't figure out how $ 18x + 7y ≡ 0 \pmod {m^2} \implies $ either $x$ or $y$ is divided by $m^2$, 
Can any one explain?

Comment: No; $18(1)+7(1)\equiv0\mod 5^2$ but $1$ is not divisible by $5^2$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner, do you want this one, or should I try clearing things up ?

Comment: Go for it, @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: Please undelete your [latest question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312304/242) (else those who may have been working on answers will have wasted their time)

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with modular arithmetic. Rather, if $x,y$ are positive, and $18x+7y\geq m^2$ (which happens if $18x+7y\equiv_{m^2}0$), then $\max(x,y)\geq \frac{m^2}{25}$.

Proof: Assume, for contradiction, that they are both smaller than $\frac{m^2}{25}$. Then we get
$$
18x+7y<18\frac{m^2}{25}+7\frac{m^2}{25}=m^2
$$

Comment: Sorry about the OP changing acceptance.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That's nothing to apologize for. If the OP thinks your answer works better for them, then changing the acceptance is their prerogative. If anything, they may have been too quick to give it out in the first place, as waiting a bit is more inviting for deeper, longer answers.