# Finding Parity of Exponent in Congruence

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, parity

Prove, z is odd if both x and y are odd and $3^x + 2^y ≡ 15^z \pmod {20}$ where $y > 1$.

Taking modulo 4 gives $ - 1 + 0 ≡ 3^z \pmod {4}$, then what?

There are several such problems, what is the general method? Please refer me a online document/book chapter if possible.

Comment: Hint:  work $\pmod 4$.

Comment: To your broader question:  I don't believe there is anything like a general method for attacking such problems.  Just work a lot of examples.

Comment: @lulu  Taking modulo 4 gives $ - 1 + (-2)^y ≡ 3^z \pmod {4}$, then what?

Comment: Well, think about it.  What is $2^y\pmod 4$?

Comment: @lulu got it! $2^y \equiv 0 \pmod4 $, also $ 9^a  \not \equiv -1 \pmod {4}$, thus $z$ can not be even, but there is no need of $y$ to be odd if $y>1$, why such condition was given? am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't understand the part about $9^a$.   $\pmod 4$ your congruence reads $-1\equiv (-1)^z\pmod 4$ and we are done.  As you say, the parity of $y$ is irrelevant, we just need $y>1$.

Comment: @lulu I stretched $z=2a$ and then saw the impossibility .

Answer (score 2):

A "general rule" is that problems like this simplify when using CRT to split them into congruences modulo smaller moduli. Doing that here reduces to simple parity arguments, namely

$\qquad\begin{align} &\bmod 20\!:\,\ 3^{\large 1+2j}+ 2^{\large 1+2k}\equiv 15^{\large z}\\[.2em]
\iff   &\bmod 20\!:\,\ 3\cdot 9^{\large j}\ + 2\cdot 4^{\large k}\ \equiv 15^{\large z}\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\  &\bmod 4\!:\,\ {-}1\equiv (-1)^{\large z} \!\iff z\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!2}\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\  &\bmod 5\!:\,\ 3(-1)^{\large j}-3(-1)^{\large k}\equiv 0\iff (-1)^{\large j}\equiv (-1)^{\large k}\iff j\equiv k\!\!\pmod{\!2} 
\end{align}$