# Help on residue: $3^x + 22^y \equiv 15^z \equiv 15 \pmod{40} $

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am reading [this note (click here and go to page 1994 for detail, in the proof of lemma 8)](https://dergipark.org.tr/download/article-file/732048), and found-

$$3^x + 22^y \equiv 15^z \equiv 15 \pmod{40} $$

now, I can derive $3^x + 22^y \equiv 15^z \ \pmod{40} $ but I cann't figure out how $3^x + 22^y \equiv 15^z\pmod{40}$ is $ \equiv 15 \pmod{40}$.

How to prove that the congruence has residue 15?

Comment: This is false.  With $(x,y)=(1,1)$ we have $3^1+22^1\equiv 15^2\not \equiv 15 \pmod {40}$.

Comment: @lulu Not a counterexample since $y > 1$ per the OP's [prior question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312304/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque  Well...but if the assumptions of the prior question apply here, then the problem is trivial, since $15^z\equiv 15\pmod {40}$ if $z$ is odd.

Comment: @lulu It is not trivial to many beginners (as witnessed by the many questions we receive on such).

Comment: On the other hand that's a pretty advanced paper for a beginner.  I'd say knowing $15^z \equiv \pm 15$ isn't some that should come to mind without thinking but that $15^z \equiv 15 \pmod{40}$ if $z$ is odd, is something any reader of this paper can verify for oneself once such a claim is made.

Comment: FWIW $(15)^z\equiv (-1)^z\pmod 8$ and $15^z\equiv 0\pmod 3$.  By Chinese remainder Th $a\equiv-1\pmod 8$ and $a\equiv 0\pmod 8$ implies $a \equiv 15\pmod {40}$ while $b\equiv 1\pmod 8$ and $a \equiv 0\pmod 8$ implies $b\equiv 25\pmod {40}$.  So $15^z \equiv 15,25\pmod {40}$ depending on whether $z$ is odd or even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \overbrace{15(15)^{\large 2n}}^{\large 15^{\:\!\LARGE 1\:\!+\,2n}\ \ }\!\bmod 40 
= \color{#0a0}5(3(\!\overbrace{15)^{\large 2n}}^{\large (-1)^{\LARGE 2n}}\!\!\bmod 8) 
= \color{#c00}{15}\,\ $ [so $\ 15^{\large 2k}\equiv 15(\color{#c00}{15})\equiv 25\,$ for $\,k>0\,$]

using $\ \color{#0a0}ab\bmod \color{#0a0}ac = \color{#0a0}a(b\bmod c) = $ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) (mDL) to factor out $\,\color{#0a0}{a = 5}$

**Remark** $ $ The CRT argument in [fleablood's  comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312369/help-on-residue-3x-22y-equiv-15z-equiv-15-pmod40/3312392#comment6815052_3312369) is essentially equivalent to the above. But - as above - the mDL is much easier to apply due to its *operational* form. This is explained further in the linked answer (see the "Linked" questions there for many more examples). Viewed inductively, mDL reduces the induction to the above *trivial induction* $\ (-1)^{\large 2n} \equiv 1\ $ (compare lulu's answer here).

Comment: Note that $\,z\,$ is odd (say $\,z = 1+2n)$ by the prior sentence in Lemma $8$ (= your [prior question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3312594/242))

Comment: little confused ... $3^x + 22^y  \equiv 15 \pmod{40} \implies  -1 + 0 \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ is true but the paper says $3^x + 22^y  \equiv 15 \pmod{40} $ has no solution when $y>1$, how is that??

Comment: @Andrew reduced $\!\bmod 8\!:\,\ 3+(-2)^{\large y}\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\, (-2)^{\large y}\equiv 4\,\Rightarrow\, y=2,\,$ contra $\,y\,$ odd. We don't even need the above for that since $15^{\large z}\equiv (-1)^{\large z}\equiv -1\,$ by $\,z\,$ odd.

Comment: ok , for $y>1$ there is no solution but from  $3 + (-2)^ y \equiv -1 \pmod 8 \implies 3 -2 +1 \equiv0 \pmod 8$ which is also impossible if we put $y= 1$ then why the author said there is solution for $y=1$?

Comment: @Andrew They claim that there are no solutions if $y>1$ so **if** a solution exists (in this case) then it must have $y = 1.\ \ $

Comment: the author said "So $ y = 1$ when $m ≡ 3, 27 (mod 40). $" explicitly in the next line , without any "if" and further investigating $y=1$ .... should I ask this in a separate post for elaborate explanation? Please note that, I am beginner .

Comment: @Andrew The goal of Lemma 8 is to show that positive solutions must have $y = 1$  when  $\,m\not\equiv 0\pmod{\!5}\,$ and $\,m\not\equiv \ldots \pmod{120}.\,$ The Lemma does not claim that a solution always exists when $\,y= 1.\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

If the assumptions of [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312304/finding-parity-of-exponent-in-congruence) hold here, then we know that $z$ is odd.

But for odd $z$, $15^z\equiv z \pmod {40}$.

To see this,  We note that $15^2=225\equiv 25\pmod {40}$ and $$15^3\equiv 15\times 25\equiv 15\pmod {40}$$  Then $$15^4=15^3\times 15\equiv 15^2\equiv 25 \pmod {40}$$ and  $$15^5\equiv 15^4\times 15\equiv 25\times 15\equiv 15 \pmod {40}$$   and so on.

By induction, we deduce that $15^{2n}\equiv 25\pmod {40}$ and $15^{2n+1}\equiv 15 {\pmod {40}}$.